# How do I use Javascript to perform a string split and access the values of an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have been trying to perform a split, but so far I have not had success.

Here is what I have so far:

I initialize a simple String:

```
var str = "matt.williams:STRING:ClassWork|1902122:STRING:AskAFriend";
```

My next step is then to output the values of the Array:

```
var m = str.split("|");
var x = new Array();
x=m;

for (z in x)
{
    document.write(z + "<br />");
}
```

However, it produces this:

```
0
1
```

But What I want to output is this:

```
matt.williams:STRING:ClassWork
1902122:STRING:AskAFriend
```

Comment: Note that in JavaScript you don't need to declare an array just so that you can assign the result of split to it, so `var x = str.split("|");` suffices.

Comment: By the way, `for (z in x)` could potentially fail if any other script on the same page modifies Array.prototype in any way. You're better off with a regular ++z loop.

Comment: @Neil : ok so like this  `for (z=0; z<x.Count();z++)`  why did you do ++z?

Comment: @Neil: Ok, precrement, i didnt realize that was available

Comment: It's just a style thing, some people think z++ is a bad habit in case you accidentally use it in a context where it's more expensive than ++z.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line:

```
document.write(z + "<br />");
```

to

```
document.write(x[z] + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is giving you the *indexes* of your array, not the actual values.  Change it to:

```
for (z in x)
{
    document.write(x[z] + "<br />");
}
```

Or just use an old fashioned for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    document.write(x[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set so many variables. You can split and iterate on the returned array.

```
str.split("|").forEach(function(i){ document.write(i+"<br />"); });
```

Comment: +1 I like how forEach will cut the need for the array with index, but I do like to have one variable to collect the Array. It feel more readable to me.

Comment: Right, but isn't that JQuery? I am not allowed to use that.

Comment: It's a 1.6 method, missing from IE8 and earlier; you can added it to the Array prototype if needed (I do).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @jmulligan - *is* that jQuery?  jQuery uses each, doesn't it? Where does forEach come from?

Comment: I'm not sure if it originated in jQuery; I was focused on other languages when JavaScript 1.6 was released. It's native in any modern browser and can be shimmed into older ones.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these answers are correct, I just wanted to add that `split()` returns an Array so you don't need to add another.

```
var str = "matt.williams:STRING:ClassWork|1902122:STRING:AskAFriend";
var m = str.split("|");

for (z in m) {
    document.write(m[z] + "<br />");
}
```